# Little task with JAVA and text file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a little problem with a java code. I am still learning and following a guide to display text from a file. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class FileExample
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        double decimal;
        int integer;
        String name;
        
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("fileExample.txt"));
    
        while (file.hasNext())
        {
            name = file.next();
            integer = file.nextInt();
            decimal = file.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf("%1s has taught %1d students and has earned $%1.2f dollars.\n\n", name, integer, decimal);
        }
    }
}
```

The text file is like this:

> Rado 12345 12345.6789  Adams 1111 1111111.11

Compiler gives me no errors, but when I execute the code I get these:

> java FileExample
>
> Exception in thread "main"
> java.util.InputMismatchException
>
> at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
>
> at FileExample.main(FileExample.java:17)

Where is the problem?

Comment: I just compiled your program with not error! and is able to output as desired.

Comment: What is your system's locale setting? (How do write decimal numbers, with a point `1.23` or comma `1,23`?

Comment: What part of [the doc of that exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) is not helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to change the format of your text file--and usually you can't anyway. Just set the correct `Locale` with scanner.useLocale(locale), https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useLocale-java.util.Locale-.

If the text file use an English decimal mark use Locale.ENGLISH, e.g.